# fitting a circle to a binary image

Tags: python, image-processing, scikit-image

I have been using skim age's thresholding algorithms to get some binary mask. For example, I obtain binary images like this:

[image: Binary image obtained as a result of Otsu thresholding]

What I am trying to figure out is how can I fit a circle to this binary mask. The constraint is the circle should cover as much of the white areas as possible and the whole circumference of the circle should lie entirely on the white parts.

I have been wrecking my head on how I can do this efficiently but have come up with no solution that works.

One approach I thought that might be something is:

- Find some optimal center of the image/circle (I am not sure how to do this yet. Perhaps some raster scan like approach).
- Compute circle for increasing radiii and figure out when it starts getting out of the white area or outside the image.
- Then the centroid and radius will describe the circle.

Comment: A very simple way to do it is to resize the image to a single column of pixels (i.e. width=1) and then look for the brightest pixel in that column which will tell which row has the most white pixels in it. Then resize the original image to a single row of pixels (i.e. height=1) and look for the brightest pixel in that row which will tell you which column has the most white pixels in it. You then have the centre of the circle since it is where the two diameters cross.

Comment: I will give this a shot, just out of curiosity :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a solution that tries to make an optimal circle fit via minimization.  It soon becomes apparent that the bubble isn't a circle :)  Note the use of "regionprops" for easily determining area, centroid, etc. of regions.

[image: Circle fit to bubble]

```
from skimage import io, color, measure, draw, img_as_bool
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


image = img_as_bool(io.imread('bubble.jpg')[..., 0])
regions = measure.regionprops(measure.label(image))
bubble = regions[0]

y0, x0 = bubble.centroid
r = bubble.major_axis_length / 2.

def cost(params):
    x0, y0, r = params
    coords = draw.disk((y0, x0), r, shape=image.shape)
    template = np.zeros_like(image)
    template[coords] = 1
    return -np.sum(template == image)

x0, y0, r = optimize.fmin(cost, (x0, y0, r))

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f, ax = plt.subplots()
circle = plt.Circle((x0, y0), r)
ax.imshow(image, cmap='gray', interpolation='nearest')
ax.add_artist(circle)
plt.show()
```

Comment: This is super nice. I guess the proper image-processing way to do it! I have been hacking bad solutions all day...

Comment: I modified it slightly to fit an ellipse. Turns out that was the best for my needs. Thanks for this. This region props method is quite useful.

Comment: @Luca Look at my answer. I'd argue that it should be more robust and give more accurate results.

Comment: I upvoted your solution @user2970139--I think that is a very elegant approach.

Comment: @StefanvanderWalt We should probably add that example to the example page for circle fitting... (This is Johannes, btw)

Comment: Elegant, trying to figure out how to do this for fitting a rectangle(s) to a binary image like this one..

Answer (score 6):

This should in general give very good and robust results:

```
import numpy as np
from skimage import measure, feature, io, color, draw
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = color.rgb2gray(io.imread("circle.jpg"))
img = feature.canny(img).astype(np.uint8)
img[img > 0] = 255

coords = np.column_stack(np.nonzero(img))

model, inliers = measure.ransac(coords, measure.CircleModel,
                                min_samples=3, residual_threshold=1,
                                max_trials=500)

print(model.params)

rr, cc = draw.disk((model.params[0], model.params[1]), model.params[2],
                   shape=img.shape)

img = img * 0.5
img[rr, cc] += 128

plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

[image: circle fit to speech bubble]

Comment: This is an interesting approach as well. I have to give it a try as well but I will probably only get to it tomorrow. I am guessing the features are only going to be detected at the circle circumference?

Comment: This works well with this image but when you have more elliptical images, it seems to have issues.

Comment: @Luca Then use an appropriate model for elliptical images. See `skimage.measure.EllipseModel`.

Comment: Could this be generalized to fitting a rectangle ?

Answer (score 3):

This is actually a mostly solved problem in image processing. Looks like what you want is a [Hough Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform#Circle_detection_process), specifically the circular or elliptical kind. I believe the circular one is a bit less computationally intensive in general.

[Here](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/edges/plot_circular_elliptical_hough_transform.html) are some code examples for scikit-image that show pretty much exactly what you're trying to do. And here is a link to the [documentation](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.transform.html?highlight=hough_circle#skimage.transform.hough_circle).

Comment: A faster ring detector, based on ridge edges + the Hough transform, is available here: https://github.com/eldad-a/ridge-directed-ring-detector

Comment: Updated link to [scikit-image Hough transform example](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/edges/plot_circular_elliptical_hough_transform.html)

Answer (score 1):

**Updated Answer**

Actually, if you use *Connected Components Analysis*, a.k.a *Blob Analysis*, you can do it with ImageMagick much more succinctly and accurately like this:

```
convert 3J3qz.jpg                                  \
   -define connected-components:verbose=true       \
   -define connected-components:area-threshold=100 \
   -connected-components 8 null:
```

**Output:**

```
Objects (id: bounding-box centroid area mean-color):
  0: 720x576+0+0 370.6,322.1 213779 srgb(0,0,0)
  13: 488x513+104+0 347.7,250.7 200941 srgb(255,255,255)   <-- answer
```

which shows your largest blob (the speech bubble) has its centroid at coordinates 347,250 from the top-left corner, and also gives you the bounding box which measures 488x513 pixels and its top-left corner is at 104,0 from which you can derive a radius.

I can mark these with ImageMagick like this:

```
convert 3J3qz.jpg \
   -fill red -draw "rectangle 342,245 352,255" 
   -stroke red -fill none -draw "rectangle 104,0 592,513" 
   out.png
```

[image]

**Original Answer**

As you are curious... you can do what I was suggesting with ImageMagick in two lines:

```
convert 3J3qz.jpg -resize 1x! -colorspace gray txt:

# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 1,576,255,gray
0,0: (66,66,66)  #424242  gray(66)
0,1: (70,70,70)  #464646  gray(70)
0,2: (72,72,72)  #484848  gray(72)
0,3: (76,76,76)  #4C4C4C  gray(76)
...
0,152: (176,176,176)  #B0B0B0  gray(176)
0,153: (176,176,176)  #B0B0B0  gray(176)
0,154: (177,177,177)  #B1B1B1  gray(177)
0,155: (177,177,177)  #B1B1B1  gray(177)
0,156: (177,177,177)  #B1B1B1  gray(177)
0,157: (177,177,177)  #B1B1B1  gray(177)
0,158: (178,178,178)  #B2B2B2  gray(178)
0,159: (178,178,178)  #B2B2B2  gray(178)
0,160: (179,179,179)  #B3B3B3  gray(179)
0,161: (179,179,179)  #B3B3B3  gray(179)
0,162: (179,179,179)  #B3B3B3  gray(179)
0,163: (179,179,179)  #B3B3B3  gray(179)
0,164: (179,179,179)  #B3B3B3  gray(179)
0,165: (179,179,179)  #B3B3B3  gray(179)
0,166: (179,179,179)  #B3B3B3  gray(179)
0,167: (179,179,179)  #B3B3B3  gray(179)
0,168: (180,180,180)  #B4B4B4  gray(180)
0,169: (180,180,180)  #B4B4B4  gray(180)
0,170: (180,180,180)  #B4B4B4  gray(180)
0,171: (180,180,180)  #B4B4B4  gray(180)
0,172: (180,180,180)  #B4B4B4  gray(180)
0,173: (180,180,180)  #B4B4B4  gray(180)
0,174: (180,180,180)  #B4B4B4  gray(180)
0,175: (180,180,180)  #B4B4B4  gray(180)
0,176: (181,181,181)  #B5B5B5  gray(181)
0,177: (181,181,181)  #B5B5B5  gray(181)
0,178: (182,182,182)  #B6B6B6  gray(182)
0,179: (182,182,182)  #B6B6B6  gray(182)
0,180: (182,182,182)  #B6B6B6  gray(182)
0,181: (182,182,182)  #B6B6B6  gray(182)
0,182: (182,182,182)  #B6B6B6  gray(182)
0,183: (182,182,182)  #B6B6B6  gray(182)
0,184: (183,183,183)  #B7B7B7  gray(183)
0,185: (183,183,183)  #B7B7B7  gray(183)
0,186: (183,183,183)  #B7B7B7  gray(183)
0,187: (183,183,183)  #B7B7B7  gray(183)
0,188: (183,183,183)  #B7B7B7  gray(183)
0,189: (183,183,183)  #B7B7B7  gray(183)
0,190: (183,183,183)  #B7B7B7  gray(183)
0,191: (183,183,183)  #B7B7B7  gray(183)
0,192: (184,184,184)  #B8B8B8  gray(184)
0,193: (184,184,184)  #B8B8B8  gray(184)
0,194: (184,184,184)  #B8B8B8  gray(184)
0,195: (184,184,184)  #B8B8B8  gray(184)
0,196: (184,184,184)  #B8B8B8  gray(184)
0,197: (184,184,184)  #B8B8B8  gray(184)
0,198: (184,184,184)  #B8B8B8  gray(184)
0,199: (184,184,184)  #B8B8B8  gray(184)
0,200: (185,185,185)  #B9B9B9  gray(185)
0,201: (185,185,185)  #B9B9B9  gray(185)
0,202: (185,185,185)  #B9B9B9  gray(185)
0,203: (185,185,185)  #B9B9B9  gray(185)
0,204: (185,185,185)  #B9B9B9  gray(185)
0,205: (185,185,185)  #B9B9B9  gray(185)
0,206: (185,185,185)  #B9B9B9  gray(185)
0,207: (185,185,185)  #B9B9B9  gray(185)
0,208: (186,186,186)  #BABABA  gray(186)
0,209: (186,186,186)  #BABABA  gray(186)
0,210: (186,186,186)  #BABABA  gray(186)
0,211: (186,186,186)  #BABABA  gray(186)
0,212: (185,185,185)  #B9B9B9  gray(185)
0,213: (186,186,186)  #BABABA  gray(186)
0,214: (186,186,186)  #BABABA  gray(186)
0,215: (186,186,186)  #BABABA  gray(186)
0,216: (186,186,186)  #BABABA  gray(186)
0,217: (186,186,186)  #BABABA  gray(186)
0,218: (186,186,186)  #BABABA  gray(186)
0,219: (186,186,186)  #BABABA  gray(186)
0,220: (186,186,186)  #BABABA  gray(186)
0,221: (186,186,186)  #BABABA  gray(186)
0,222: (186,186,186)  #BABABA  gray(186)
0,223: (186,186,186)  #BABABA  gray(186)
0,224: (186,186,186)  #BABABA  gray(186)
0,225: (186,186,186)  #BABABA  gray(186)
0,226: (186,186,186)  #BABABA  gray(186)
0,227: (186,186,186)  #BABABA  gray(186)
0,228: (187,187,187)  #BBBBBB  gray(187)
0,229: (187,187,187)  #BBBBBB  gray(187)
0,230: (187,187,187)  #BBBBBB  gray(187)
0,231: (187,187,187)  #BBBBBB  gray(187)
0,232: (187,187,187)  #BBBBBB  gray(187)
0,233: (187,187,187)  #BBBBBB  gray(187)
0,234: (187,187,187)  #BBBBBB  gray(187) <---- max=234
0,235: (187,187,187)  #BBBBBB  gray(187)
0,236: (187,187,187)  #BBBBBB  gray(187)
0,237: (187,187,187)  #BBBBBB  gray(187)
0,238: (187,187,187)  #BBBBBB  gray(187)
0,239: (187,187,187)  #BBBBBB  gray(187)
0,240: (187,187,187)  #BBBBBB  gray(187)
0,241: (187,187,187)  #BBBBBB  gray(187)
0,242: (187,187,187)  #BBBBBB  gray(187)
0,243: (187,187,187)  #BBBBBB  gray(187)
0,244: (187,187,187)  #BBBBBB  gray(187)
0,245: (187,187,187)  #BBBBBB  gray(187)
0,246: (187,187,187)  #BBBBBB  gray(187)
0,247: (187,187,187)  #BBBBBB  gray(187)
0,248: (187,187,187)  #BBBBBB  gray(187)
0,249: (187,187,187)  #BBBBBB  gray(187)
0,250: (187,187,187)  #BBBBBB  gray(187)
...
0,573: (0,0,0)  #000000  gray(0)
0,574: (0,0,0)  #000000  gray(0)
0,575: (0,0,0)  #000000  gray(0)
```

And the other side

```
convert 3J3qz.jpg -resize x1! -colorspace gray txt: 

# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 720,1,255,gray
0,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  gray(0)
1,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  gray(0)
2,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  gray(0)
3,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  gray(0)
4,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  gray(0)
...
241,0: (219,219,219)  #DBDBDB  gray(219)
242,0: (220,220,220)  #DCDCDC  gray(220)
243,0: (220,220,220)  #DCDCDC  gray(220)
244,0: (221,221,221)  #DDDDDD  gray(221)
245,0: (222,222,222)  #DEDEDE  gray(222)
246,0: (223,223,223)  #DFDFDF  gray(223)
247,0: (223,223,223)  #DFDFDF  gray(223)
248,0: (224,224,224)  #E0E0E0  gray(224)
249,0: (224,224,224)  #E0E0E0  gray(224)
250,0: (225,225,225)  #E1E1E1  gray(225)
251,0: (227,227,227)  #E3E3E3  gray(227)
252,0: (229,229,229)  #E5E5E5  gray(229)
253,0: (230,230,230)  #E6E6E6  gray(230)
254,0: (231,231,231)  #E7E7E7  gray(231)
255,0: (232,232,232)  #E8E8E8  gray(232)  <--- max=255
256,0: (231,231,231)  #E7E7E7  gray(231)
257,0: (231,231,231)  #E7E7E7  gray(231)
258,0: (231,231,231)  #E7E7E7  gray(231)
259,0: (231,231,231)  #E7E7E7  gray(231)
260,0: (230,230,230)  #E6E6E6  gray(230)
261,0: (230,230,230)  #E6E6E6  gray(230)
262,0: (230,230,230)  #E6E6E6  gray(230)
263,0: (230,230,230)  #E6E6E6  gray(230)
264,0: (230,230,230)  #E6E6E6  gray(230)
265,0: (230,230,230)  #E6E6E6  gray(230)
266,0: (230,230,230)  #E6E6E6  gray(230)
267,0: (230,230,230)  #E6E6E6  gray(230)
268,0: (229,229,229)  #E5E5E5  gray(229)
269,0: (230,230,230)  #E6E6E6  gray(230)
270,0: (229,229,229)  #E5E5E5  gray(229)
271,0: (229,229,229)  #E5E5E5  gray(229)
272,0: (229,229,229)  #E5E5E5  gray(229)
273,0: (229,229,229)  #E5E5E5  gray(229)
274,0: (229,229,229)  #E5E5E5  gray(229)
275,0: (229,229,229)  #E5E5E5  gray(229)
276,0: (229,229,229)  #E5E5E5  gray(229)
277,0: (229,229,229)  #E5E5E5  gray(229)
278,0: (229,229,229)  #E5E5E5  gray(229)
279,0: (229,229,229)  #E5E5E5  gray(229)
280,0: (229,229,229)  #E5E5E5  gray(229)
281,0: (229,229,229)  #E5E5E5  gray(229)
282,0: (229,229,229)  #E5E5E5  gray(229)
283,0: (229,229,229)  #E5E5E5  gray(229)
284,0: (229,229,229)  #E5E5E5  gray(229)
285,0: (229,229,229)  #E5E5E5  gray(229)
286,0: (229,229,229)  #E5E5E5  gray(229)
287,0: (230,230,230)  #E6E6E6  gray(230)
288,0: (230,230,230)  #E6E6E6  gray(230)
289,0: (230,230,230)  #E6E6E6  gray(230)
290,0: (230,230,230)  #E6E6E6  gray(230)
291,0: (230,230,230)  #E6E6E6  gray(230)
292,0: (230,230,230)  #E6E6E6  gray(230)
293,0: (230,230,230)  #E6E6E6  gray(230)
294,0: (230,230,230)  #E6E6E6  gray(230)
295,0: (231,231,231)  #E7E7E7  gray(231)
296,0: (231,231,231)  #E7E7E7  gray(231)
297,0: (231,231,231)  #E7E7E7  gray(231)
298,0: (231,231,231)  #E7E7E7  gray(231)
299,0: (231,231,231)  #E7E7E7  gray(231)
300,0: (231,231,231)  #E7E7E7  gray(231)
301,0: (231,231,231)  #E7E7E7  gray(231)
302,0: (231,231,231)  #E7E7E7  gray(231)
303,0: (231,231,231)  #E7E7E7  gray(231)
304,0: (232,232,232)  #E8E8E8  gray(232)
305,0: (231,231,231)  #E7E7E7  gray(231)
306,0: (231,231,231)  #E7E7E7  gray(231)
307,0: (231,231,231)  #E7E7E7  gray(231)
308,0: (231,231,231)  #E7E7E7  gray(231)
309,0: (232,232,232)  #E8E8E8  gray(232)
310,0: (232,232,232)  #E8E8E8  gray(232)
311,0: (232,232,232)  #E8E8E8  gray(232)
312,0: (233,233,233)  #E9E9E9  gray(233)
313,0: (232,232,232)  #E8E8E8  gray(232)
314,0: (232,232,232)  #E8E8E8  gray(232)
315,0: (232,232,232)  #E8E8E8  gray(232)
316,0: (232,232,232)  #E8E8E8  gray(232)
317,0: (232,232,232)  #E8E8E8  gray(232)
318,0: (232,232,232)  #E8E8E8  gray(232)
319,0: (232,232,232)  #E8E8E8  gray(232)
320,0: (232,232,232)  #E8E8E8  gray(232)
321,0: (233,233,233)  #E9E9E9  gray(233)
322,0: (233,233,233)  #E9E9E9  gray(233)
323,0: (233,233,233)  #E9E9E9  gray(233)
324,0: (233,233,233)  #E9E9E9  gray(233)
325,0: (233,233,233)  #E9E9E9  gray(233)
326,0: (233,233,233)  #E9E9E9  gray(233)
327,0: (233,233,233)  #E9E9E9  gray(233)
328,0: (233,233,233)  #E9E9E9  gray(233)
329,0: (233,233,233)  #E9E9E9  gray(233)
330,0: (233,233,233)  #E9E9E9  gray(233)
331,0: (233,233,233)  #E9E9E9  gray(233)
332,0: (233,233,233)  #E9E9E9  gray(233)
333,0: (233,233,233)  #E9E9E9  gray(233)
334,0: (233,233,233)  #E9E9E9  gray(233)
335,0: (233,233,233)  #E9E9E9  gray(233)
336,0: (233,233,233)  #E9E9E9  gray(233)
337,0: (233,233,233)  #E9E9E9  gray(233)
338,0: (233,233,233)  #E9E9E9  gray(233)
339,0: (233,233,233)  #E9E9E9  gray(233)
340,0: (233,233,233)  #E9E9E9  gray(233)
341,0: (233,233,233)  #E9E9E9  gray(233)
342,0: (233,233,233)  #E9E9E9  gray(233)
343,0: (233,233,233)  #E9E9E9  gray(233)
344,0: (233,233,233)  #E9E9E9  gray(233)
345,0: (233,233,233)  #E9E9E9  gray(233)
346,0: (233,233,233)  #E9E9E9  gray(233)
347,0: (233,233,233)  #E9E9E9  gray(233)
348,0: (233,233,233)  #E9E9E9  gray(233)
349,0: (233,233,233)  #E9E9E9  gray(233)
350,0: (233,233,233)  #E9E9E9  gray(233)
351,0: (233,233,233)  #E9E9E9  gray(233)
352,0: (233,233,233)  #E9E9E9  gray(233)
353,0: (233,233,233)  #E9E9E9  gray(233)
354,0: (233,233,233)  #E9E9E9  gray(233)
...
717,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  gray(0)
718,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  gray(0)
719,0: (0,0,0)  #000000  gray(0)
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I am trying to code this in python now. let's see how that goes.

Comment: This method is not robust against the cropping shown in the example image.

Comment: @StefanvanderWalt Yes, you are right - I misunderstood the question altogether - but I will leave the answer as it may be useful for other people looking to solve the problem I thought I was solving :-)

Comment: The implementation I show below takes care of the cropping but yes, it is very hacky.

Answer (score 0):

For someone looking to code Mark's suggestion in python, it is quite easy.

```
collapsed = np.sum(binary_array, axis=0)
# These indices will be already sorted
indices = np.where(collapsed == collapsed.max())[0]
c = indices[int(round((len(indices) - 1) / 2))]

# Same for rows
collapsed = np.sum(binary_array, axis=1)
# These indices will be already sorted
indices = np.where(collapsed == collapsed.max())[0]
r = indices[int(round((len(indices) - 1) / 2))]

# circle center is (r, c)
```

This code takes care when your shape is not spherical and the collapsing along an axes can have multiple maxima. In that case, it takes the middle one (the one that can give you the largest radius when you fit the circle).