# TypeError: Label image must be of integral type

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, matplotlib, scikit-image

I would like to detect some circles (circle like cells) in an image, and then measure the greenness (number of green pixel?) in each circle.

I am using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28281742/fitting-a-circle-to-a-binary-image) discussion with the following code:

```
from skimage import io, color, measure, draw, img_as_bool
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


image = img_as_bool(color.rgb2gray(io.imread('0.06_3a.jpg')))
regions = measure.regionprops(image)
bubble = regions[0]

y0, x0 = bubble.centroid
r = bubble.major_axis_length / 2.

def cost(params):
    x0, y0, r = params
    coords = draw.circle(y0, x0, r, shape=image.shape)
    template = np.zeros_like(image)
    template[coords] = 1
    return -np.sum(template == image)

x0, y0, r = optimize.fmin(cost, (x0, y0, r))

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f, ax = plt.subplots()
circle = plt.Circle((x0, y0), r)
ax.imshow(image, cmap='gray', interpolation='nearest')
ax.add_artist(circle)
plt.show()
```

I get the following error:

```
    /home/mahsa/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/skimage/util/dtype.py:118: UserWarning: Possible sign loss when converting negative image of type float64 to positive image of type bool.
  .format(dtypeobj_in, dtypeobj_out))
/home/mahsa/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/skimage/util/dtype.py:122: UserWarning: Possible precision loss when converting from float64 to bool
  .format(dtypeobj_in, dtypeobj_out))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "img.py", line 28, in <module>
    regions = measure.regionprops(image)
  File "/home/mahsa/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/skimage/measure/_regionprops.py", line 539, in regionprops
    raise TypeError('Label image must be of integral type.')
TypeError: Label image must be of integral type.
```

1. What does this error mean and what should i do to fix it?
2. After fixing this error, how do i loop through all the pixels in each region to count the green pixels?

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Can you provide the entire traceback?

Comment: When you report a python error, always show the *complete* traceback (i.e. the complete error message).  It includes useful information.  Most importantly, it shows which line triggered the error.

Comment: OKay, I am sorry, i edited the post. :)

Answer (score 2):

The error occurs here:

```
regions = measure.regionprops(image)
```

Apparently `regionprops()` requires its argument to have an integer data type.  You created `image` with

```
image = img_as_bool(color.rgb2gray(io.imread('0.06_3a.jpg')))
```

which means that the data type of `image` is `bool`.  `bool` is not a subtype of `np.integer`, so `regionprops` complains.

A quick fix that you can try is:

```
regions = measure.regionprops(image.astype(int))
```

but you should probably rethink the way you created `image`.  Why did you use `img_as_bool()`?